# Mongo change stream + Kafka vs Monga kafka Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka

Is there any preference in using Mongo Kafka Connector vs Mongo change stream + separate Kafka publisher? is there any out of box feature enabled in Mongo Kafka connector? does it support change stream + resume token facility in same manner? If we have to choose one which we should choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo  Source Connector is using the mongodb change stream and kafka producer under the hood... you would need to have Kafka Connect service established to run the connector on it...

It is question of if you want to use already made solution which is tested and supported by a solid company

or

Building your own solution to already solved problem ...

You will have "harder" time to build your own code and maintain it - but most flexibility

You will have safer, tested, easier and faster to deploy already made solutions but it is fitting most use cases and might not fit 100% to your own use case, so less flexibility...

Check the MongoDb Connector documentation,  if your use case fits to its description and not something that out of scope / standard,

I personally do not recommend building solutions to already solved problems

Comment: Thank you.. I was thinking on similar line.. tried to read but dint get any straight comparison matrix so asked..